# Animated TV show about a boy working as a courier, set in a high-tech post apocalyptic world

Tags: story-identification, tv, anime, cartoon

There was an animated show on TV about a boy working as a courier, set in a high-tech post apocalyptic world. He finds old relics that grant him powers.

In one episode the boy got a belt that gave him a bubble shield, later he got more upgrades. The boy was always in blue, like [Mega Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mega_Man) and they were competing against rival guilds for rep. His friend was a girl in pink armor. They had hover boards.

It aired in 2003-2006 on local TV (in South Africa so either SABC 1, 2 or 3) at 16h00, along with the show [*URBO: The Adventures of Pax Afrika*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URBO:_The_Adventures_of_Pax_Afrika).

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you see this?  Where?  What language was it in?  Live-action or animated?

Comment: Can you remember any more details? This is kind of a popular premise-- *Snow Crash*, *The Courier*...

Comment: Yes it was animated. It aired on local tv between 2003-2006 english. In one ep. The boy got a belt that gave him a bubble shield, later he got more upgrades.

Comment: Ps. Im in S.A So local tv for me is sabc 1, 2 and 3. It aired everyday at 16h00 along with a show call urbo, pax africa.

Comment: The boy was always in blue kinda like mega-man and they were competing agenst rivel gulds for rep.His friend was a girl in pink armore. They had hover boards. Hope this is enough info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly *Get Ed* (2005).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Get_Ed):

> In the series, Ed is an "electro-genetically" enhanced teen who works for Dojo Deliveries, a courier service, in the futuristic Progress City. Ed uses his cyber sleuthing skills to thwart identity theft and other information-based crimes. He and his courier pals Burn, Deets, Fizz, and Loogie (accompanied by his puppet Dr. Pinch), along with their friend and mentor Ol’ Skool, must battle the ultimate evil – Bedlam, an industrialist who has taken over a significant portion of Progress City, by means of stealing from, data mining, or outright destroying his competitors.

I can't find evidence of the setting being post-apocalyptic, but other than that, the rest matches nicely:

- the release date
- futuristic, high-tech city
- boy is a courier, wears blue armor-like bike gear, has a female friend dressed in pink (and another in purple), both have hoverboards:

  [image: Get Ed crew]
- the Wikia says the following about [Artifacts](https://getedtvseries.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Artifacts):

  > Artifacts are the pieces of Ed that are still missing and scattered about Progress City. **Each artifact enhances Ed's already outstanding abilities, grants him some sort of new power**, or links him to his destiny. Ed is drawn to the objects and they are often what the Dojo Crew and Bedlam are after. [...]
  >
  > **Phase Belt**- An artifact that is in the form of a belt and allows the wearer to have the ability to teleport and bend the light around them so that it cloaks their presence, making them invisible.

---

Found with [IMDb's advanced title search](https://www.imdb.com/search/title/), with the following criteria ([5 results](https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?title_type=tv_series&release_date=,2007-12-31&genres=animation&plot=courier)):

- TV series
- Animation
- Release date up to 2007
- Plot contains "courier"

Comment: Thank thats the one. Yea my memory gets a littel hazzy   but thanks.

Comment: @Gideon no worries, you're welcome! Enjoy the re-watch!